# JSON specifies "any UNICODE character"?

Tags: json, unicode, encoding

Maybe this is just my unfamiliarity with unicode, so please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Looking at http://json.org/, the spec says that a string can include "any UNICODE character", but this confuses me.

- JSON is a communication format
  correct? At the core of it,
  everything must translate down to
  bytes.
- In contrast, UNICODE is a
  logical format and must be encoded to
  be able to transmit it, right?

So what did they mean there?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

```
3.  Encoding

   JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
   UTF-8.

   Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII
   characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet
   stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking
   at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets.

           00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE
           00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE
           xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE
           xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE
           xx xx xx xx  UTF-8
```

Comment: I'm always confused when people say "encoded in Unicode", since (as I understand it) Unicode is a character set, not an encoding.  Shouldn't that be "SHALL use the Unicode character set, with a default encoding of UTF-8"?  I'm surprised to see such a thing in an RFC.

Answer (score 3):

JSON is a serialization format which can include UNICODE characters. The byte representation of this unicode string is usually sent over the wire, normally through the HTTP protocol which uses HTTP headers to specify the encoding to the client which is UTF-8.

Comment: The latest RFC states:
    Note:  No "charset" parameter is defined for this registration.
      Adding one really has no effect on compliant recipients.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that everything must translate into bytes, and usually that usually occurs through a UTF (Unicode Transformation Format).  The JSON RFC explains in [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-3) how to tell what UTF is being used.